# How to package translation files for a Python application?

Tags: python, gtk, translation, gettext, packaging

I have an application written in Python and Gtk which contains a number of translation string inside, properly marked using `_()`.
The repository of this application contains a set of  `.po` files for different languages which are compiled and sorted out in a directory layout fine to be loaded by `gettext` when the `setup.py` of the application is run.

The current project looks currently like this:

```
/
/po/fr.po
/mo/fr/LC_MESSAGES/my-app.mo
/my-app/__init__.py
/setup.py
```

`gettext.install()` is currently called several times, trying various "well-known places" (like `/usr/share/locale`, `dirname(my-app.__file__ ) + "../mo"`, etc.) As I said before, the  `.mo` files are not stored in the repository itself, but generated on the fly when `setup.py` is launched.

I would like to know what would be the "best way" to deal with those files. Specifically, I would like to find a way which:

- allows the developers to use the translations without having to install the application somewhere (working straight into the repository);
- allows people who wants to install it to have the translation files spread out at the right place;
- allows packagers (for Linux distributions for example) to deal easily with those translation files.

My questions would then be:

1. Where do I store my .mo files?
2. How do I find where those files are (considering the points above)?
3. How do I package those files (Python-wise speaking)?